# Documentation for training a named entity recognizer model from an IOB annotated train set

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Is there any documentation which can be used to find out which properties should be set for training a Stanford NER model from a train set with IOB annotation tags in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed example located here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

see:
"Training or retraining new models"